# .net 5 webapi with cli

Tags: c#, .net-5

Is it a way to handle in one project .net 5 webapi (which it will taking commanda via REST API) and to make access from local host, where the service is hosted, by cli?
Form example to able making commands  super_service doSth

Comment: Sure, just call the api using CURL or WGET, or even TELNET if you're brave

Answer (score 0):

To access a web api from the command line with a command, you'll need to build a cli tool that actually fires an HTTP request.

So with only the webservice, no it's not possible.

But build another tool (console project "super_service") that takes an input ("doSth") and from that decides which route to call, then uses an `HttpClient` to do an HTTP request to localhost.

Edit: To call the tool from anywhere, you'll have to add its bin directory to your PATH.